# 'pyrcc5' is not recognized as an internal or external command (Python PyQt5 & LabelImg)

Tags: python, pyqt5, lxml, labelimg

Installed pyqt5 and lxml via pip for labelimg but receiving the error when trying to execute pyrcc5:

'pyrcc5' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Using anaconda therefore it has installed to miniconda3\envs\tf\Lib\site-packages\pyqt5. Adding the directory to system path has not helped.

Reinstalled pyqt5, no luck

**EDIT: SOLVED BY INSTALLING TO THE BASE CONDA ENVIRONMENT WITH PIP
pip install pyqt5
pip install lxml**

Answer (score 0):

Something similar to this : [labelImg: 'pyrcc5' is not recognized as an internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58140305/labelimg-pyrcc5-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

Are you sure that what you set in `PATH` is the full directory pointing to where pyrcc5.exe is found?

Comment: There is no pyrcc5.exe in the folder